# Push Menu to right

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, nav

Here are images of what I am attempting to do [This is the main image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS5Rs.jpg) then when you click on the menu [everything moves right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19VMl.jpg)

I got the right push menu, toggle switch menu plus main divs figured out. I need to have the 3 lines that are clicked on centered in the div, I need the div to take up the length of the page and I need for the logo to sit in the center of the div.

Here's my current code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;

}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #212121;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav p {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 100px;
        color: #CACFD2;
        font-size: 12px;
        left:10%;
        }

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.sidenav a.mail {
        color: #CACFD2;
        font-size: 12px;
        left:10%;
        padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;

    }


#logozone {
    background-color: #212121;
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
}

 @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 2px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Current Projects</a>
   <p>client info</p>

 </div>


<div id="logozone">
   <span style="text-align:center; font-size:30px;color:#CACFD2;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; 
   <div><img src="logo.jpg"></div>
   </div>

 <script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("logozone").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("logozone").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
</script>

</div>

<div>This is a test</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance ... this is coding I haven't worked with before

Comment: create menu bar and vertical bar differently , create vertical bar with in content left side, and if user click on the icons in vertical bar then menu bar will appear . .

Comment: These might helpful to you. [link 1](https://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/) [link 2](https://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/index3.html)

Comment: I removed your site link because that site can change or disappear in five minutes and won't help anyone in the future. Provide a sample image and post it here, not a third party site, for the same reason.

Comment: Thank you @CodeMonkey I found those yesterday while hunting. They do what I've already accomplished. My problem is I need a div next to the menu with the open lines and the ability to put a logo that runs vertcally, then yet another div for the main content. Those examples just have the main menu and the main content. I'm out of my comfort zone and ballpark on this one :(

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the postions of #Logomenu and #logo from absolute to relative and there is no need to add z-index in sidenav class, let it be on the same canvas.